# foreach loop bigger than using perl

Tags: perl, if-statement, foreach, conditional-statements

I have a hash of hashes, were I need to compare all the "master keys" with each other (these are numeric). Here is my code for that:

```
foreach my $masterkey1 (keys %HOH){
foreach my $masterkey2 (keys %HOH){
        if ($masterkey1 > $masterkey2){
            ... do some stuff...
        }
    }
}
```

However to decrease memory use is it possible to combine the if statement with the second foreach loop.

maybe something like

```
foreach my $masterkey1 (keys %HOH){
    foreach my $masterkey2 (keys %HOH < $masterkey1){
        ... do some stuff...
    }
}
```

- Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach my $masterkey1 (keys %HOH){
    foreach my $masterkey2 (grep { $_ < $masterkey1 } keys %HOH){
        ... do some stuff...
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this will be any more efficient. The inner loop has to do two passes through the keys: one to find all the keys that are less than `$masterkey1`, then to actually "do some stuff".

Best would be to save the key list in a separate variable:

```
@keys = keys %HOH;
foreach my $masterkey1 (@keys) {
    foreach my $masterkey2 (@keys) {
        if ($masterkey1 > $masterkey2) {
           # do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy and sort the keys:

```
my @keys = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %HOH;
```

Now that the list is sorted, you can grab each key off the end of the list and compare it with everything before it:

```
while (my $masterkey1 = pop @keys) {
    foreach my $masterkey2 (@keys) {
        # do some stuff with $masterkey1 and $masterkey2
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, he inner loop should be over the smaller keys. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the improvements!

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to have two nested loops scanning through your list of keys.  The time it takes to run will increase exponentially with the number of keys in the top-level hash, which can cause major issues unless the hash is (and will always remain) relatively small.

You didn't say what you actually want to accomplish, but, since you're comparing values for which is greater, you'll probably want to start off with a `sort`.  The best I can give you that's functionally identical to the posted code is:

```
my @masterkeys = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %HOH;
for my $outer (1 .. $#masterkeys) {
  for my $inner (0 .. $outer - 1) {
    # We already know $masterkeys[$outer] > $masterkeys[$inner],
    # so no need to test that
    ... do some stuff ...
  }
}
```

This will at least be a little more efficient than your posted code, but, if you tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish, I suspect that there's still a lot of improvement possible.

**Edit:**  Per OP's comment on this answer, "*I need to compare all of the masterkeys and count how many keys they have i common.*"

Here's how to find the common keys in two hashes:

```
my %count;
$count{$_}++ for keys %hash1;
$count{$_}++ for keys %hash2;
my @keys_in_common = grep { $count{$_} == 2 } keys %count;
```

The time required for this process will increase linearly with the total number of keys in the two hashes, so it remains efficient for very large data sets.

Comment: `sort { $a <=> $b } keys %HoH`

Comment: Thanks Zaid and Ikegami, for making my sort numeric instead of asciibetical. I always seem to forget that...

Comment: It is very big data sets Im using, so it is very important that the code is efficient.

Comment: I need to compare all of the masterkeys and count how many keys they have i common. Dont know if it makes a difference

Comment: @user2335015: If I understand your comment correctly, you're actually comparing the keys of two different hashes (`%HOH1` and `%HOH2`, rather than a single `%HOH`) and you're looking for keys which are identical in both hashes (`$key1 eq $key2` rather than `$key1 > $key2`). Is that correct? If so, it makes a HUGE difference. That can be done with only a single pass over each hash. I'll edit my answer to include the way to do that.